# Populate 3rd party element from Redux with JSON instead of innerHTML or attributes

Tags: javascript, redux

I am using a 3rd party library to generate a sortable grid that expects to be fed JSON data, is there a way to send part of the redux store to this non-react grid other than as a react component, attribute or innerHtml since it does expect JSON? The challenges are that all my redux scripts are modules which is a scoping issue since, in this case, the 3rd party element is wrapped in asp.net so I can't expose it to a function (though it can call a javascript function to get the data), and that I need to be able to subscribe to changes, this has proven unnecessarily difficult so far.

Comment: Can you give some more specific examples of what your code actually looks like? There's not enough information to be able to answer anything.

Comment: @markerikson I've actually changed the question to address the underlying issue, instead of the specific part I am working on right now

Comment: Can you give some actual code examples? I still don't get what you're actually trying to do. A Redux store has nothing to do with `innerHTML`, I don't know what you mean by "all my Redux scripts are modules", and I don't see how that has anything to do with passing data from Redux to some third-party library.  Have you actually read through [the Redux store API reference](https://redux.js.org/api/store) and the tutorials on how to use Redux?

Comment: @markerikson I have. What I mean is when you render you either render to react components, use attributes for web components or you just set innerHtml of target html right? Is there a way to render JSON, and subscribe that render function to changes as the 3rd party expects JSON? I don't want to add specific code because then I will get a specific solution rather than a solution that could be applied generally to similar problems, and returning and using JSON will be a huge part of this project. If it were up to me we would just use react anyway, but it is not.

Comment: This question is very unclear and needs code samples illustrating what you’re trying to accomplish. SO questions should be about specific coding problems.

Comment: @bryan60 I'm prepared to link to dozens of well received questions on SO that shows that is not the case, and the fact that I could set a bounty on a canonical question shows that that is not the case. And I'm not sure how much more clear I can be, redux renders to the view, otherwise it is useless on its own. How can I create a subscribed render function that returns JSON or a function that returns json instead of injecting content into markup or via a component (be it a web component or specifically a react component), if it is at all possible for any situation where this is the goal?

Comment: If you can help this be less ambiguous in any way please feel free to ask clarifying questions or make edits to the question.

Comment: Some questions don’t need code because it’s clear what they’re asking. This is not one of those questions. You have no answers despite a bounty bc no one knows what you’re asking. Code will clear up what you are trying to do.

Comment: @bryan60 I'll just go ahead and throw some code up when I can sit down, though in my experience very specific questions for a generic problem rarely go answered on SO unless it is a quick and easy quesiton; there is a graveyard of hundreds, if not thousands, of these questions.

Comment: You might want to read through my post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/), my talk [A Deep Dive into React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/), and the slides on [Redux/UI Layer Integration](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/presentations/workshops/redux-fundamentals/ui-layer.html), which talk about how Redux actually interacts with a UI.

Comment: @markerikson While I, unfortunately, can't use react for this app the Redux/UI layer integration might have what I need, at the very least I can use it to clarify my question, i.e. slide 5 uses innerHtml in the way I was referring to, I'll follow up after giving it a thorough read, thank you

Comment: Per the slides, the overall workflow is: 1) Action is dispatched; 2) Redux store runs all subscriber callbacks; 3) Subscriber callbacks should call `store.getState()`; 4) Do something useful with that state value, depending on your own app. For a typical UI layer, it's running some kind of a selector function to see what data this specific part of the UI cares about, diffing that vs the previously extracted value, and forcing an update for this UI section if that's changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `store.getState()` to get the current state of the store.

You may want to attach the store on to the `window` to give it global scope when you create it,

```
window.redux = { store }
```

or if using modern js, create a wrapper export function in the file that you create it

```
export const getStore = () => store
```

So that you can then do

```
getStore().getState()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are using some third-party element in a react app that takes data in the form of JSON? Without more details on the third-party library its hard to give a proper answer but I'll give it a shot.

Whatever this library is, you have to render it somehow at some point. Since we don't know what you are using I am going to pick jQuery.

Assume the following usage

```
$("#grid").initializeGrid(data);
```

You can expect the react component to be something like

```
const GridWrapper = (props) => {
  const tableData = useSelector(selectTableJson);

  useEffect(() => {
    $("#grid").initializeGrid(data);
  }, [tableData]);

  return (
    <div id="grid" />
  );
}
```

Basically what is happening is you select the data from the redux store, and then initialize the third party component with that data.